# matlab - GUIDE with input arguments - uimenu autoupdates its submenus

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a struct that contains some debug-options i.e: `dbs = struct('db1', 0, 'db2', 1)`. And user can add more debug options to this struct (`db3`, `db4` etc.) later, as well as change the value of existing fields `db1`, `db2`.

I want to create a GUI `dbGUI` with uimenu `Debug options`. `dbGUI` should take `dbs` as input argument, so i put `varargin` to my GUI's OpeningFcn, so i can call the GUI from command window like `dbGUI(dbs)`:

```
function dbGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.dbNames = fieldnames(varargin{1});
handles.dbVal = cellfun(@(i) varargin{1}.(i), handles.dbNames);
```

The uimenu "Debug options" should show submenus corresponding with `dbs`'s fields. What i want is: how to auto-update the submenus when user modifies the struct `dbs` from outside of the GUI (means in Matlab command window)?

As suggested from @marco wassmer below, the struct `dbs` should be declared as a handle class inherited from `dynamicprops` and using `addlistener`. The problem is: when the user changes `dbs` in Command Window, the function `updateFoo` cannot get the `dbGUI`'s handles, thus cannot update the value to handles, and finally the uimenu_CallbackFcn cannot update the new fields and values.

Note: I tried to use GUI programmatically, but i prefer GUIDE since it's easier for me to layout the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that it could be much more simpler:

I just declare `dbs` as a handle class. Then in GUI's OpeningFcn, assign a field to `dbs`: `handles.myvar = varargin{1};`. Since `dbs` now is a handle class, everything i do with `dbs` outside the GUI (i.e in Command Window) will also be updated to the GUI's handles.

```
function dbGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.var = varargin{1};
% other fields in handles
guidata(hObject, handles);

function db_menu_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
disp('Updated variable: ');
disp(handles.var);
% here do whatever i want ....
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Update the menue every time the user clicks it, something like this:

  ```
  handles.dbs_menue = uimenu(f,'Label','Debug options','Callback','@foo')

  .
  .
  .

  function foo(hObj)
      dbs=getVariable('base','dbs')
      handles.dbO = fieldnames(dbs.dbOptions)
      % and replace all menue items...
  ```

according to matworks this is **not** recomended,
source: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uimenu-properties.html#prop_Callback

- The otehr way would be to make dbs into a handle object and add a listener in the GUI. Maybe a bit more elaborate than you had in mind, but here it goes.
  Don't worry it will work almost the same as a struct...
  first you need to make a handle object and therefore a class:

  ```
      classdef dbs_class < dynamicprops
  properties (Access='private')
      lhs=[];
  end
  events
      StateChange
  end
  methods
      function obj=dbs_class(a)
          addlistener(obj,'PropertyAdded',@eventPRadd);
          %addlistener(obj,'StateChange',@(varargin) disp('change'));
      end

      function eventPRadd(obj,evnt)
          names=fieldnames(obj);
          meta_p=obj.findprop(names{end});
          meta_p.SetObservable=true;
          obj.lhs.(names{end})=addlistener(obj,names{end},'PostSet',@(varargin) notify(obj,'StateChange'))
          obj.(names{end})=0;
          notify(obj,'StateChange')
      end

      function removeprop(obj,name)
          meta_p=obj.findprop(name);
          delete(meta_p)
          delete(obj.lhs.(name))
          notify(obj,'StateChange')
      end    
  end
  ```

  end

Then make one of these:

```
dbs=dbs_class(1);
```

This, the variable `dbs` that is, 'behaves' now almost like a struct, execpt when some one changes one of the properties, the event `StateChange` will be triggerd.

In the opening function all you need to do is add the listener  and callback to the objects event 'StateChange':

```
function gui_test(dbs_in)
handles.fig=figure('Tag','fig');
addlistener(dbs_in,'something_changed',@updateFoo);
handles.dbO = fieldnames(dbs_in);
handles.dbmenu= uimenu('Label','Debug');
for n=1:numel(handles.dbO)
    if dbs_in.(handles.dbO{n})==1
        uimenu(handles.dbmenu,'Label',handles.dbO{n},'Callback',@(varargin) disp(['Debugg mode :' handles.dbO{n}]));
    end
end
guidata(handles.fig, handles);

function updateFoo(src,~)
handles=guidata(findobj('Type','Figure','Tag','fig'))
handles.dbO = fieldnames(src);
delete(get(handles.dbmenu,'Children'))
for n=1:numel(handles.dbO)
    if src.(handles.dbO{n})==1
        uimenu(handles.dbmenu,'Label',handles.dbO{n},'Callback',['disp([''DebuggingMode :'  handles.dbO(n) '])']);
    end
end
guidata(handles.fig, handles);
```

Source: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But i not only want to modify the value of fields, but also add more fields. I found something usefull with `dynamicprops`, but couldnt manage to make it run ...

Comment: @scmg I changed the anwser to use the `dynamicprops` -class, thanks for the input, quite intresting this class

Comment: thanks again, but unfortunately, your sample code for the class has so many minor bugs, and i finally dont know the GUI doesnt work because of the errors in GUI's functions, or of the errors in the class ...

Comment: well, the main problem is: if you modify `dbs_class`, then you are in Matlab's command window, and `handles=guidata(gcf)` in your `updateFoo` just creates new blank figure than gives you the handle of your GUI.

Comment: I figuered you had that part already, but i changed the anwser to include a  working example. Note: Edited Class to to set default value for new props to 0

Comment: read my above comment!!! and i updated the question as well, hope i pointed out the remaining problem clearly

Comment: ok, i think i got it now, to find the handles use handles=guidata(findobj('Type','Figure','Tag','dbGUI')). I assuem dbGUI is the tag of your Figure, you can change it with the propertyinspector in guide